# Understanding Azure AD Access token flow

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am trying to understand the various steps involved in OAuth access token request/response flow with Azure Active Directory.

I created a high level flow diagram to illustrate what I think is happening.

Scenario: A web app wants to login a user using Azure AD, get user's permission to read his/her emails and tries to read an email of the user.

[image]

Things I am not so clear about:

1. Does the access token encode all the information I mentioned (appid, scope, resource, userid)?
2. When validating the token at step #7, why does it need to check whether the incoming token's scope is correct (email.read)? If the app already has `read` access to email (granted in step 3 and 4), why do we need to validate the incoming scope again? If the app sends an access token that is issued for say counting emails, can't we use that scope to read? Because we know that the app has permission to read emails, what's the harm in using an access token (validates appid) issued for a different purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations for your nice findings first of all.

Now moving to concern you are on...

1. **Does the access token encode all the information I mentioned (appid, scope, resource, userid)**

You are closed enough though, but for more clarity `Resource` and `Scope` are same. As you know azure active directory has two version ***[V1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-overview)*** and version ***[V.20](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-overview)***

> `Resource` is in V1.0 which has replaced on V2.0 as `Scope` both
>   define user access domain.

**Now  let's dig down what token actually  contains**

As per your question, there are many `OAuth 2.0` [protocol supports in azure active directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-scenarios) so each protocol has different work around. I am explaining two for you.

**Azure Active Directory v2.0 and the [OAuth 2.0 resource owner password credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc)**

**ROPC Token Example POSTMAN**

Let's examine a token example using ROPC  protocol. See the screen shot below =>

[image]

If you have a look on the token claims at https://jwt.io/ you would get your answer

see the screen shot below:

[image]

Here in this protocol we have

> appId , UserId , Resource/Scope and many more information marked on picture.

But all other token protocol does not contain the same information. You could check [OpenID Connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc) protocol token claims as well.

2. **Why do we need to validate the incoming scope again?**

OAuth was designed for cases where Application X needs access to resources (e.g., "my information" or "my email address" or "my calendar") controlled by Application Y and belonging to User A — User A may want to grant access to those resources on Application Y, but he doesn't want to give Application X his actual username/password credentials. So an access token is used as an alternative credential for a resource on Application Y. Access tokens can be revoked independently of username/password credentials and are, ideally, tightly scoped to only allow access to specific resources.

Using OAuth 2 for authentication overloads that model in ways that can be risky. Look at the example above, and imagine it being used for authentication. If Application X uses that access token for authentication, then it's taking a token that grants access to resources on Application Y, and using it to grant access to its own resources. Maybe that's splitting hairs, because the important thing is that we know that the act of granting an access token via OAuth 2 implies that the user has successfully authenticated.

The problem is that the access token doesn't say anything about which application the end user authenticated for. So what happens if Application Z also has an access token for User A's resources on Application Y? If Application Z can get Application X to use this access token, then it has access to User A's resources on Application X. That's bad. User A may have trusted Application Z to access his resources on Application Y, but User A certainly never granted consent for Application Z to access his resources on Application X. For more explanation you could refer [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8237/is-there-any-drawback-of-using-oauth-pseudoauthentication-as-opposed-to-openid)

**Another reason**

According to my experience but I am not pretty sure about that we often update our application permission and scope of access, if it does not check always we would not able to access our latest credentials as well.  You could also refer some good thread [here](https://habiletechnologies.com/blog/pros-cons-using-authentication/)

Comment: @Prabu Have a look on this answer and try out your own token claims, let me know if you have any more query. Thanks